# Linking To V8 Snapshot

Tags: dll, linker, v8

I'm trying to link to a V8 library (v8_base.lib) that I've compiled in Visual Studio 2008 with the /MDd option. When I link to it from another library I get errors like:

```
Error 4 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int const v8::internal::Snapshot::size_" (?size_@Snapshot@internal@v8@@0HB) v8_base.lib myapp
```

How can I resolve these issues?

(List of all errors)

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static int __cdecl v8::internal::NativesCollection<0>::GetBuiltinsCount(void)" (?GetBuiltinsCount@?$NativesCollection@$0A@@internal@v8@@SAHXZ) referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall v8::internal::Heap::CreateInitialObjects(void)" (?CreateInitialObjects@Heap@internal@v8@@AAE_NXZ)    v8_base.lib pconn
Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int __cdecl v8::internal::NativesCollection<0>::GetBuiltinsCount(void)" (?GetBuiltinsCount@?$NativesCollection@$0A@@internal@v8@@SAHXZ)   v8_base.lib pconn
Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int __cdecl v8::internal::NativesCollection<0>::GetBuiltinsCount(void)" (?GetBuiltinsCount@?$NativesCollection@$0A@@internal@v8@@SAHXZ)   v8_base.lib pconn
Error   4   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int const v8::internal::Snapshot::size_" (?size_@Snapshot@internal@v8@@0HB)  v8_base.lib pconn
Error   5   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int const v8::internal::Snapshot::size_" (?size_@Snapshot@internal@v8@@0HB)  v8_base.lib pconn
Error   6   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int const v8::internal::Snapshot::size_" (?size_@Snapshot@internal@v8@@0HB)  v8_base.lib pconn
Error   7   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static unsigned char const * const v8::internal::Snapshot::raw_data_" (?raw_data_@Snapshot@internal@v8@@0PBEB)  v8_base.lib pconn
Error   8   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int const v8::internal::Snapshot::raw_size_" (?raw_size_@Snapshot@internal@v8@@0HB)  v8_base.lib pconn
Error   9   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static unsigned char const * const v8::internal::Snapshot::context_raw_data_" (?context_raw_data_@Snapshot@internal@v8@@0PBEB)  v8_base.lib pconn
Error   10  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int const v8::internal::Snapshot::context_raw_size_" (?context_raw_size_@Snapshot@internal@v8@@0HB)  v8_base.lib pconn
Error   11  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int const v8::internal::Snapshot::new_space_used_" (?new_space_used_@Snapshot@internal@v8@@0HB)  v8_base.lib pconn
Error   12  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int const v8::internal::Snapshot::pointer_space_used_" (?pointer_space_used_@Snapshot@internal@v8@@0HB)  v8_base.lib pconn
Error   13  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int const v8::internal::Snapshot::data_space_used_" (?data_space_used_@Snapshot@internal@v8@@0HB)    v8_base.lib pconn
Error   14  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int const v8::internal::Snapshot::code_space_used_" (?code_space_used_@Snapshot@internal@v8@@0HB)    v8_base.lib pconn
Error   15  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int const v8::internal::Snapshot::map_space_used_" (?map_space_used_@Snapshot@internal@v8@@0HB)  v8_base.lib pconn
Error   16  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int const v8::internal::Snapshot::cell_space_used_" (?cell_space_used_@Snapshot@internal@v8@@0HB)    v8_base.lib pconn
Error   17  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int const v8::internal::Snapshot::large_space_used_" (?large_space_used_@Snapshot@internal@v8@@0HB)  v8_base.lib pconn
Error   18  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int const v8::internal::Snapshot::context_size_" (?context_size_@Snapshot@internal@v8@@0HB)  v8_base.lib pconn
Error   19  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class v8::internal::Vector<char const > __cdecl v8::internal::NativesCollection<0>::GetRawScriptSource(int)" (?GetRawScriptSource@?$NativesCollection@$0A@@internal@v8@@SA?AV?$Vector@$$CBD@23@H@Z) referenced in function "public: class v8::internal::Handle<class v8::internal::String> __thiscall v8::internal::Bootstrapper::NativesSourceLookup(int)" (?NativesSourceLookup@Bootstrapper@internal@v8@@QAE?AV?$Handle@VString@internal@v8@@@23@H@Z)  v8_base.lib pconn
Error   20  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class v8::internal::Vector<char const > __cdecl v8::internal::NativesCollection<0>::GetRawScriptSource(int)" (?GetRawScriptSource@?$NativesCollection@$0A@@internal@v8@@SA?AV?$Vector@$$CBD@23@H@Z)   v8_base.lib pconn
Error   21  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class v8::internal::Vector<char const > __cdecl v8::internal::NativesCollection<0>::GetScriptName(int)" (?GetScriptName@?$NativesCollection@$0A@@internal@v8@@SA?AV?$Vector@$$CBD@23@H@Z) referenced in function "private: static bool __cdecl v8::internal::Genesis::CompileBuiltin(class v8::internal::Isolate *,int)" (?CompileBuiltin@Genesis@internal@v8@@CA_NPAVIsolate@23@H@Z) v8_base.lib pconn
Error   22  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class v8::internal::Vector<char const > __cdecl v8::internal::NativesCollection<0>::GetScriptName(int)" (?GetScriptName@?$NativesCollection@$0A@@internal@v8@@SA?AV?$Vector@$$CBD@23@H@Z) v8_base.lib pconn
Error   23  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class v8::internal::Vector<char const > __cdecl v8::internal::NativesCollection<1>::GetRawScriptSource(int)" (?GetRawScriptSource@?$NativesCollection@$00@internal@v8@@SA?AV?$Vector@$$CBD@23@H@Z) referenced in function "private: static bool __cdecl v8::internal::Genesis::CompileExperimentalBuiltin(class v8::internal::Isolate *,int)" (?CompileExperimentalBuiltin@Genesis@internal@v8@@CA_NPAVIsolate@23@H@Z)    v8_base.lib pconn
Error   24  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class v8::internal::Vector<char const > __cdecl v8::internal::NativesCollection<1>::GetScriptName(int)" (?GetScriptName@?$NativesCollection@$00@internal@v8@@SA?AV?$Vector@$$CBD@23@H@Z) referenced in function "private: static bool __cdecl v8::internal::Genesis::CompileExperimentalBuiltin(class v8::internal::Isolate *,int)" (?CompileExperimentalBuiltin@Genesis@internal@v8@@CA_NPAVIsolate@23@H@Z)  v8_base.lib pconn
Error   25  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static int __cdecl v8::internal::NativesCollection<0>::GetDebuggerCount(void)" (?GetDebuggerCount@?$NativesCollection@$0A@@internal@v8@@SAHXZ) referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall v8::internal::Genesis::InstallNatives(void)" (?InstallNatives@Genesis@internal@v8@@AAE_NXZ)  v8_base.lib pconn
Error   26  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static int __cdecl v8::internal::NativesCollection<1>::GetBuiltinsCount(void)" (?GetBuiltinsCount@?$NativesCollection@$00@internal@v8@@SAHXZ) referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall v8::internal::Genesis::InstallExperimentalNatives(void)" (?InstallExperimentalNatives@Genesis@internal@v8@@AAE_NXZ)   v8_base.lib pconn
Error   27  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static int __cdecl v8::internal::NativesCollection<1>::GetDebuggerCount(void)" (?GetDebuggerCount@?$NativesCollection@$00@internal@v8@@SAHXZ) referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall v8::internal::Genesis::InstallExperimentalNatives(void)" (?InstallExperimentalNatives@Genesis@internal@v8@@AAE_NXZ)   v8_base.lib pconn
Error   28  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static int __cdecl v8::internal::NativesCollection<0>::GetIndex(char const *)" (?GetIndex@?$NativesCollection@$0A@@internal@v8@@SAHPBD@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall v8::internal::Debug::Load(void)" (?Load@Debug@internal@v8@@QAE_NXZ)    v8_base.lib pconn
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to add the `v8_nosnapshot` project to your project and have v8_base depend on it. This will resolve all of these errors.