# Load a dll in Javascript V8

Tags: javascript, c++, dll, v8

Hi I am trying to load a simple Hello World DLL in javascript (v8 engine).

I thought that would be possible because there are already a few .dll files in the vgcgi/lib folder that can be loaded simply.

For example:

```
require("socket"); // lib/socket.dll
require("mysql"); // lib/mysql.dll
..
```

when I try to load my own DLL

```
require("mycsharpdll");
require("mycppdll");
```

I am getting following error:

```
Error: Cannot initialize shared library '\lib\mycpp.dll'
Error: Cannot initialize shared library '\lib\mycsharpdll.dll'
```

Is there actually a way to load dll files into javascript v8?

I know there is edge.js to implement .NET parts into my javascript - but i really need to 
load a specific dll :)

Comment: I suspect that the libraries V8 is willing to load are those that follow its own integration spec. Some random .NET DLL probably won't do that.

Comment: You can't do that.  You need to use http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html

Comment: thank u.
But the point is that I don't want to use nodejs :)
I should have mentioned that

Comment: do you know if it is possible to write v8 addons without including node.h ?

Comment: Those are native unmanaged dll's, not managed dll's. There is a huge difference between native (c, C++) dll's and .NET (C#, VB, F#, ...) dll's

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linking To V8 Snapshot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745040/linking-to-v8-snapshot)

Comment: If you're in a .NET environment, you should consider using the ClearScript V8 wrapper (or something similar such as Jurassic); you can then load the DLL in the .NET framework and pass whatever you need from the DLL into an executable statement inside of the V8 wrapper.